# Can't find old emails after upgrading to Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: evolution

Can anyone tell me where I can find my old emails that existed prior to upgrading new version of ubuntu 11.10?

Comment: How did you upgrade your system?

Comment: Accepted the automatic upgrade notification

Comment: You should be able to open Evolution manually then, because it would not have been removed. You're probably seeing Thunderbird when you open your mail.

Comment: I was actually using evolution, however, I just set up Thunderbird and it found all my old emails.  Thanks for you help.  I didn't know about the other email program.  Can I import the emails from Thunderbird back into evolution?

Comment: I don't think you can, but you can open a new question about it. If my answer answered the question for you, click the tick next to it.

Comment: Kaye Lowes, did you get any resolution for this in Evolution? did you ever try again?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to open Evolution manually then, because it would not have been removed. You're probably seeing Thunderbird when you open your mail.

To open Evolution (if you are using Unity), open the Dash and type Evolution, then click the icon that comes up (if Evolution is still there that is).

If Evolution does not show up, then you can install it from the software centre and access your old emails. Then you can migrate to Thunderbird (if you like) or remain with Evolution.

Comment: Evolution IS the program that is opening, yet my inbox is still empty.  I can access my subfolder, contacts, and even calendar events, but my Inbox is empty...I've even tried removing the account profile and recreating it.

Comment: @sadmicrowave: this is not the place - you already asked another question. Flagging as not-relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking in `.local/share/evolution/mail/local`

I had a power failure in the middle of upgrading from 11.04 to 11.10. It may have nothing to do with losing the Evolution email, but after restarting and finishing the upgrade - I opened Evolution and though it listed my mail, it failed to open any. After closing and opening Evolution again, all my email was GONE! I was particularly bummed about lost drafts I had been working on... But, I did find and recover them.

If your problem is similar:

1. Make a copy of `.local/share/evolution/mail/local` 
   Put the copy in some non-hidden folder like Documents
2. Open   Evolution - Main - On This Computer
3. Select the folder you want to restore, such as the Inbox
4. Select (top menu) File - Import...
5. From the Evolution Import Assistant choose:

   - Continue
   - select Import a single file - Continue
   - select a file name (if it's in Documents, click your user name then Documents)
     look for the file that only says Inbox (after selecting it may take a while   before you get you next prompt)
   - it should says file type Berkeley Mailbox,  then just click Continue
   - it should say the Destination folder, if good, Continue
   - Then click Apply to import the data

Comment: what if my 'inbox' is not a folder inside `.../mail/local/` ?