# Lost Evolution Inbox During 11.10 upgrade

Tags: 11.10, upgrade, evolution, email

I just upgraded to 11.10 and lost my inbox messages in Evolution.  All subfolders and their content exists and continues to receive messages but the Inbox folder remains empty (although I know I have been getting messages [via iPhone inbox]).

I've tried searching for `/home/[myuser]/.local/share/evolution/mail/local/inbox` but the last dir `inbox` does not exist (even when showing hidden files and folders).

How can I retrieve my messages and restore my inbox?

I have attached some screenshots.
showing no email in inbox:

[image]

showing updated and current email in subfolder:
[image]
Please Help!!

Comment: possible duplicate -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/66166/cant-find-old-emails-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-11-10

Comment: workaround -> https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evolution/+question/174156

Comment: Thank you for these links; however, they were not helpful for me.  They describe importing the `.../mail/local/inbox` dir in evolution; however, this directory does not exist for me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OMG Fixed!

I unsubscribed and resubscribed my INBOX by right-clicking on my account-name and clicking 'Manage Subscriptions'.  Once I did this, the emails for the INBOX appeared but the sub-folders were gone.  Using the same method I unsubscribed and resubscribed to all subfolders and Viola! I now have active email for all folder subscriptions.  WEIRD STUFF!!!

Answer (score 0):

@sadmicrowave have you checked for a folder /home/[myuser]/.evolution/mail/local/inbox?

Might be stored under that directory (if not erased) as that is where 11.04 stored some of my old mail files and always backed up those copies prior to upgrade for re-import post-upgrade (just as a precaution and regular step of safe-keeping). Have been utilising Thunderbird as of late though, too lazy to do otherwise (my honest reason).

So, after seeing the comment below, this appears to be an issue that is misinterpreted. The problem appears to be that mistakenly, have thought that your issue was one of an upgrade loss of your inbox, whereas the issue is that youa re actually still receiving email, however, the emails are not showing within your inbox in Evolution.

If this is correct so far, then perhaps the issue is within a setting in your Server Settings for the email account itself. Knowing how those settings are set may shed some light on the issue here; could you perhaps share that information (without revealing any specific personally identifiable information) so that a determination could be made to determine if the incoming emails are being sent to the correct folders?

That might prove beneficial.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion; however, `.../.evolution/` does not exist for me.

Comment: I'm not sure what 'server settings' you are looking for me to post.  Obviously I'm not going to take screenshots of each and every Account Editor screen.  Other than that, I use IMAP with SSL encryption, and SMTP with TLS encryption for sending.  I check for mail every 1 minute and check for messages in all folders and sub-folders.  Additionally, (forgive my ignorance) but I'm not sure how you can say that missing the `/.evolution/` and `.../.local/share/evolution/mail/local/inbox` directories may be related to a mail server setting issue...

Comment: Trying to help determine where your incoming emails are being sent to by default. Believe there is a way in the Evolution settings to have them sent to another folder other than "inbox". Seem to recall having made that mistake once before, but as stated, has been a while since I have used Evolution. Would suggest checking to see if the emails are bound for another folder other than the inbox; that is all I can think of without any information to review. HTH. Have a nice day.